# Can calls to member functions of function parameters be used as template arguments?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, sfinae, compiler-bug

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
auto f(T x) -> std::enable_if_t<x.size() == 4>;
```

is valid for Clang and MSVC, but invalid according to GCC. Which is correct? https://godbolt.org/z/q8v4G5vn6

Comment: This might be the same as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80242. Which would mean it is valid and a GCC bug.

Comment: No, constexpr is a compile time thing. a constexpr function call that potentially depends on the function value is not a valid template argument in C++.

In C++, template arguments must be constant expressions, which means their values must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the above code is well-formed and this is an instance of the [GCC bug 80242](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80242) you have found.

`x` is type-dependent on `T`, and `x.size()` can be a constant expression for some `x`.
A compiler should never dismiss this code as ill-formed before instantiating `f`, because `x.size()` is possibly a constant expression.

Even if `x` is an object that doesn't exist at compile time, we can access its size:

```cpp
std::array<int, 10> x;
constexpr std::size_t size = x.size();
```

... and all major compilers accept this, as they should.
The reason why this is okay to write is that `.size()` for `std::array` never accesses the value or address of the object `x`, only the template arguments that `std::array` was given.
This means that in your function, if `T = std::array<...>`, then `x.size()` is a constant expression and should be usable as a template argument for `std::enable_if_t`.

The error output for GCC is also totally nonsensical, which further reinforces the idea that this is a compiler bug:

```
<source>:5:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    5 | auto f(T x) -> std::enable_if_t<x.size() == 4>;
      |                                              ^
<source>:5:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid
<source>:5:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid
<source>:5:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid
<source>:5:46: error: template argument 1 is invalid
<source>:5:16: error: invalid use of template-name 'std::enable_if_t' without an argument list
    5 | auto f(T x) -> std::enable_if_t<x.size() == 4>;
      |                ^~~
```